# How to set max width of an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

On my website I would like to display images uploaded by user in a new window with a specific size (`width: 600px`). The problem is that the images may be big. So if they are bigger than these `600px`, I would like to resize them, preserving the aspect ratio.

I tried the `max-width` CSS property, but it doesn't work: the image's size doesn't change.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="ImageContainerr">
    <img src="DisplayImage.do?ad_id=${requestScope.advert.id}" class="Image" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
img.Image { max-width: 100%;}
div#ImageContainer { width: 600px; }
```

I also tried setting the `max-width: 600px` for an image, but doesn't work. The image is streamed from a servlet (it's stored outside Tomcat's webapps folder).

Comment: if you want it to auto scale down, just set `max-width`, don't set `max-height` and it should work. If not, post your code so others can help you to spot the problem.

Comment: I just tried your example and it works here. Are you sure you don't have the same typo in your actual html ("ImageContainerr") as here in this example?

Comment: Damn, you're right. I restarted my Tomcat and browser, tried again - and it really works fine. Thanks anyway :) The typo wasn't the case - I changed the id and class name in here so it would be easier to understand.

Comment: From this I would asume that you don't use Firebug or other developer tools. I suggest you get yourself Firebug and learn to use it. ( By inspecting these two elements you would've seen that the width wasn't added to the container. )

Comment: Look my example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cZtN/). Everything is working. If the image is larger than 600 px, then it resized. You made ​a mistake in the name of the class ImageContainer in html.

Comment: ***Warning: This question is much less broadly applicable than it initially appears.*** Looks like a lot of upvotes might be because those upvoters also missed that the `id` here didn't match the CSS. As written (20151201), this question boils down to, "CSS selectors that don't match any DOM objects don't influence appearance". ;^) (Can't figure if it'd be better to edit the question to ask what its title implies does or not...)

Comment: Intresting thing about set `max-width` for image tags with presentage, is that "browser calculation is based on the original size of the image, not the container". In your case, `img.Image { max-width: 100%;}` (100%) **means 100% of the original image's size** meanwhile you expect to be "100% of the container `div`"

Answer (score 171):

You can write like this:

```
img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ErNeT/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works perfectly!
Edit: Well, not exatcly - it also resizes images that are smaller than 600px - and that's something I don't want.

Comment: @user1315305 Look at your original example. The typo causes the CSS for the div to not match.

Comment: I down voted. What the OP want's is not what you offer. You should've also realized that that there could be a problem in OP's code cause normally what he tried, should work.. Who ever up voted, give me a reason, thanks.

Comment: It's not what the op wants..? What op wants is exactly what he tried to do, he just had a typo that forced his code to not work.

Comment: @Lollero first OP edit his question after my answer & can you explain what's wrong in my answer? thanks

Comment: Your answer is not what the OP wants? That's not an answer worth any up votes. Even if you answered before he edited, so what? Your answer is wrong.

Comment: This doesn't preserve aspect ratio in IE

Comment: Thanks for this answer, its the best one and the information you present is useful to me (I dont care about IE support either).

Comment: i have a doubt! can we give image width more than 100%??? like.....img{width:120%;}

Comment: What's the purpose of the "width:100%"? The linked fiddle seems to work fine without it? (Tested in Firefox and Safari on Mac OX)

Answer (score 24):

I see this hasn't been answered as final.

I see you have max-width as 100% and width as 600. Flip those.

A simple way also is:

```
     <img src="image.png" style="max-width:600px;width:100%">
```

I use this often, and then you can control individual images as well, and not have it on all img tags. You could CSS it also like below.

```
 .image600{
     width:100%;
     max-width:600px;
 }

     <img src="image.png" class="image600">
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that **img** tag is inline element and you can't restrict width of inline element.

So to restrict img tag width first you need to convert it into a inline-block element

```
img.Image{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That is not necessary in my experience. max-width works for me on its own. Even though the logic of not restricting inline elements width seems valid.

Answer (score 3):

Given your container width 600px.

If you want only bigger images than that to fit inside, add:
CSS:

```
#ImageContainer img {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

If you want ALL images to take the avaiable (600px) space:

```
#ImageContainer img {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Also, comments on the OP indicate that you are using a wrong id on the CSS file:  div#ImageContainer is not the same as the  <div id="ImageContainerr">

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 div#ImageContainer { width: 600px; }
 #ImageContainer img{ max-width: 600px}
```

Comment: That is not correct. Your selector means "an img element inside an Image element".

Answer (score 1):

Your css is almost correct. You are just missing `display: block;` in image css.
Also one typo in your id. It should be `<div id="ImageContainer">`

```css
img.Image { max-width: 100%; display: block; }
div#ImageContainer { width: 600px; }
```

```html
<div id="ImageContainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x600" class="Image">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the element in a div with the fixed width/height:

```
<div style="width: 600px;">
  <img src="whatever" />
</div>
```