# How to display images with fixed width and variable height

Tags: css, image-processing

I want to show user images with fixed width(300 px) and height can vary. Now problem comes when the width of uploaded image is less than 300 px.

What i want is image should be displayed in a box of 300 px in centre and with should be the actual width of the image uploaded.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? Are you trying to implement this but running into problems?  What have you done so far?

Comment: `max-width` is your friend here.

Comment: Not really a question. Please see some HTML guides like w3cschools.com

Comment: *cringe* We still direct people to w3schools?

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: don’t know why people comment if they don't want to answer the question.

Comment: Was the issue resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, to those hating on w3schools, just because you now think of yourself as an expert and know more than anybody else, for 95% of people learning html, css, JS, php, etc.  w3schools are in invaluable resource full of awesome demos and information, so no reason to "cringe" about telling people to go there.

**Your answer is here:**

http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

To summarize, you can add " max-width:100px; " to any CSS property (div, p, img, etc.)

img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
}

This is a duplicate question of this: [How to set max width of an image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078913/how-to-set-max-width-of-an-image-in-css)