# How do I make images and <figures> in my website responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, figure

I have asked something similar but I will try to make my question a little bit more specific this time.

I have made a website which has has 3 modes:

One for bigger resolutions - http://puu.sh/dBaeI/d5cdce3056.jpg

One for tablet resolutions - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc1Ga.jpg

One for mobile resolutions - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfRU6.jpg

1. As you see one my images are in a <"figure"> but I can't seem to access and edit them in media queries how can i fix this?
2. A figure will automatically create some kind of scroll thingy (which I highlighted) so you can still look at the whole picture while scrolling, how can I make my image and figure responsive?
3. With my mobile resolution my navigation overlaps other parts of the page like my image and so also the figure how can I resolve this?

Preview and code: http://www.cssdesk.com/8ZpXX (unfornately you can't see what I mean in the preview because of the images)

Comment: Please make improvements to your example so we can more easily see what's wrong. Also, post your code... without it, your question will not be helpful to future visitors and therefore is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: msdn had a pretty good article about this this month.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857356.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to shrink images with media queries and transforms, for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    #imageDiv {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
        transform: scale(0.7);
    }
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/edo2f9f8/) - you can drag the splitter between the html / css / js / output panes to see the resizing of the 3 quanta.

Re : Scaling the image causes the image to lose its centering - you can move the image back to center with more transforming, e.g.:

```
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -ms--origin: left center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
```

Comment: It kinda does work but does not give the correct results : http://puu.sh/dBnrO/2a361634e8.jpg

Comment: If you mean the alignment goes awry, I've updated. `center center` might actually be better.

Comment: Ah nice, it still looks kinda weird though because of the emty gap that has been created because of the transform isnt there any other way?

Comment: Well, instead of transforms, you could just set [`max-width`, `max-height`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078913/how-to-set-max-width-of-an-image-in-css) on each of the media query quanta? But you would need to manually grab the dimensions of the images?

Comment: what  would the code look like then?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Fray Fan Web Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>











<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>

            <h1>Fan Web Site The Fray</h1>


    <nav>
<ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="bio.html">Biography</a></li>


            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </li>
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a>

                </li>
            <li><a href="releases.html">Releases</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="singles.html">Singles</a></li>

            </li>

</ul>
    </nav>




        </header>




        <section class="border">
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/100468-fray_617_409.jpg" id="normalimg" alt="The Fray" />
                    <figcaption>The Fray</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <hgroup>
                    <h2> H2 Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                    <h3> H3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                </hgroup>
                <p>Paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </article>    
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/The Fray.png" alt="The Fray" />
                    <figcaption>The Fray</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <hgroup>
                    <h2> H2 Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                    <h3> H3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                </hgroup>
                <p>Paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </article>    
        </section>






        <aside>
            <section class="popular-songs">
                <h2>Top 5 Songs</h2>
                <a href="http://open.spotify.com/track/5fVZC9GiM4e8vu99W0Xf6J">1. How to Save a Life</a>
                <a href="http://open.spotify.com/track/4IoYz8XqqdowINzfRrFnhi">2. You Found Me</a>
                <a href="http://open.spotify.com/track/57uX2vR9j9DNiANDYfXw1i">3. Never Say Never</a>
                <a href="http://open.spotify.com/track/1N62wozuHCvczCkY4QidpP">4. Over My Head(Cable Car)</a>
                <a href="http://open.spotify.com/track/6IDDwI0YOCAUDhMZltQekS">5. Love don't die</a>
            </section>




            <section class="contact-details">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <p>Raar<br />
                    CSS<br />
                    Nog meer onzin<br />
                    Onzin</p>
            </section>



            <section class="Shit">
                <h2>News</h2>
                <p>Raar<br />
                    CSS<br />
                    Nog meer onzin<br />
                    Onzin</p>
            </section>






        </aside>




        <footer>
            &copy; Maker



            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheFray" target="_blank" align="right"><img id="imgfooter" src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/webicons2/facebook.png" border="0" style="margin:1px;"></a>


            <a href="https://twitter.com/thefray" target="_blank" align="right"><img id="imgfooter"  src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/webicons2/twitter.png" border="0" style="margin:1px;"></a>





        </footer>

    </div><!-- .wrapper -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
        body {
            color: #666666;
            background-color: #1f4643;
            background-image: url("images/Greenpower.png");
            background-position: center;
            font-family: "Cuprum", Arial;
            line-height: 1.4em;
            margin: 0px;
            text-align: auto;
            }

        .wrapper {
            width: 940px;
            margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
            /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        header {
            height: 160px;
            background-image: url(images/header3.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        h1 {
            text-indent: -9999px;
            width: 940px;
            height: 130px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        footer {
            clear: both;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #1f4643;
            height: 30px;
        }
        nav {
            clear: both;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            height: 30px;
        }















        /*(OLD BODY)  body {
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          padding: 20px 50px 150px;
          font-size: 13px;
          text-align: center;

        }

        */

        ul {
          text-align: center;
          display: inline;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
          list-style: none;
        }
        ul li {
          font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
          display: inline-block;
          margin-right: -4px;
          position: relative;
          padding: 15px 20px;
          background: #fff;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
          -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
          -o-transition: all 0.2s;
          transition: all 0.2s;
          width: 147px;
        }
        ul li:hover {
          background: #efefef;
          color: #fff;
        }
        ul li ul {
          padding: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 48px;
          left: 0;
          width: 150px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
          display: none;
          opacity: 0;
          visibility: hidden;
          -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
          -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -transition: opacity 0.2s;
        }
        ul li ul li { 
          background: #ffffff; 
          display: block; 
          color: #fff;
          border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        ul li ul li:hover, ul li .current { background: #efefef; }
        ul li:hover ul {
          display: block;
          opacity: 1;
          visibility: visible;
        }

























        section.border {
            float: left;
            width: 659px;
            border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        article {
            clear: both;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
        hgroup {
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        figure {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        #bio1 {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }

        #bio2 {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        #bio3 {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        #bio4 {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        #imgfooter {

            float: right;



        }   






        figcaption {
            font-size: 90%;
            text-align: left;
        }
        aside {
            width: 230px;
            float: left;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
        }
        aside section a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }
        aside section a:hover {
            color: #985d6a;
            background-color: #efefef;
        }
        a {
            color: #02536f;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        h1, h2, h3 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        h2 {
            margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        h3 {
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
            padding: 5px;
            color: ##02536f
        }
        aside h2 {
            padding: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
            color: #02536f;
        }
        footer {
            font-size: 80%;
            padding: 7px 0px 0px 20px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        p {

            padding: 5px;

        }

    @font-face {
    font-family: "Cuprum";
    src: url('349121094-Cuprum-Regular.eot');
    src: url('349121094-Cuprum-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('349121094-Cuprum-Regular.svg#Cuprum') format('svg'),
    url('349121094-Cuprum-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('349121094-Cuprum-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }





        @media screen and (max-width: 939px) {

             .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 600px;

            }

            img #normalimg {    




            }

            figure {






            }



            img #imgfooter {
                width: 100%;



            }

            section.border {

                    width: 85%;
            }






            ul li {

                width: 78px;



            }

        }










        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

             .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 340px;


            }

            img #normalimg {    
                width: 50%;

            }


            img #imgfooter {
                width: 100%;



            }


            ul li {

                width: 95px;



            }


            section.border {


            }



            figure {





            }


            ul li {
              font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
              display: block;
              margin-right: -4px;
              position: relative;
              padding: 15px 20px;
              background: #fff;
              cursor: pointer;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
              -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
              -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
              -o-transition: all 0.2s;
              transition: all 0.2s;
              width: 300px;

            }






        }







        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #normalimg {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On that Media Query 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

Why you never assigned the value for figure.

like 
     @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

```
 figure {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Because I was trying out things and left it blank because nothing was working.

Comment: do you try !important;
    figure{
    width: auto !important;
    height:auto !important;