# img max-width with percentage how does it work?

Tags: html, css

I am new to responsive web design and was looking at an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078913/how-to-set-max-width-of-an-image-in-css).

It doesn't really explain much but provides a solution.

If an `img` is set as `width: 100%` I understand that it will occupy 100% of the browser window or its containing element.

The `max-width` property [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) that it is used to set the max width of an element.

If I set an `img` tag to `max-width: 100%` to what element/context is the percent calculated against?

All I see is when `max-width` is used the image scales down but never up.

Max-width example: http://jsfiddle.net/ErNeT/1445/

Width example:http://jsfiddle.net/ErNeT/1446/

Answer (score 2):

> If I set an img tag to max-width: 100% to what element/context is the
>   percent calculated against?

By default an img tag has no dimension set on it.  So whatever happens, that image will never resize.  However, applying max-width will make it behave like it has 100% width.  It will resize based on the parent container BUT will stop at the maximum width the image has.  For example: if the image was sliced to have 100px width, it will resize up to 100px width.

On the other hand, by applying width (and no max-width property) it will disregard all other width properties of the image and the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `max-width` to `img` then it will be the `max-width` of its parent. If you don't specify a width for the `img` then it will not exceed it's native size.

Comment: yep this is what i'm trying to telling him haha :D

Answer (score 1):

When you set percentage values, both `width` and `max-width` are relative to the containing block. However, if the width of the containing block depends on the width of the element, the resulting layout is undefined.

From the specification,

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property

> Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is
>   calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing
>   block. If the containing block's width depends on this element's
>   width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1. Note: For
>   absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a
>   block container element, the percentage is calculated with respect to
>   the width of the padding box of that element. This is a change from
>   CSS1, where the percentage width was always calculated with respect to
>   the content box of the parent element.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths

> Specifies a percentage for determining the used value.
>   The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the containing block's width is
>   negative, the used value is zero. If the containing block's width
>   depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is
>   undefined in CSS 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view

```
if width > max-width use max-width
```

Example: Let's say you have 1 div box or Image which is you set the size of the box width > 1000px and max-width 500px. It still follow the max-width.

Example 2 - Using percentage : Let's say that div of your width set 500px, and max-width :100%; what is the result you will get ? The box div will turn 500px that is your starting point. Try shrink it. What is the result you will get next? It's turn responsive.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/cohtj62b/2/)

this is what i understand about the difference between width and max-width.

**Based on your question and fiddle, I think this is the answer what you're looking for.**

Max-width example: [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/ErNeT/1447/)
 - When you start use max-width and set 100%. let say your images size is width is 300px. Meaning that your images starting point are 300px. You aren't override the original image width.

Width example: [DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/ErNeT/1448/)
 - When you start use width and set 100%. Meaning that your image are override the original image width.

Comment: The context here is using images

Comment: it's same images or div, refresh the page and try click again the demo, i already updated the demo.